# Python: Inserting characters between other characters at random points

Tags: python

For example:

```
str = 'Hello world. Hello world.'
```

Turns into:

```
list = ['!','-','=','~','|']
str = 'He!l-lo wor~ld|.- H~el=lo -w!or~ld.'
```

Comment: what did you try? why did it fail? Is it homework?

Comment: bad idea to use `str` as a variable name

Comment: @amit I was trying something as such: return ''.join(s[i:i+4]+random.choice(list) for i in xrange(0, len(s), 4)) It was working fine, but I was looking for a better method of doing such.

Comment: @wim Yeah, I know, was just providing an example :) Thanks for the FYI though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import random

lst = ['!','-','=','~','|']
string = 'Hello world. Hello world.'


print ''.join('%s%s' % (x, random.choice(lst) if random.random() > 0.5 else '') for x in string)
```

Comment: that's a nice way to do it. +1

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that leans towards clarity, but performance-wise may not be optimal.

```
from random import randint
string = 'Hello world. Hello world.'

for char in ['!','-','=','~','|']:
    pos = randint(0, len(string) - 1)  # pick random position to insert char
    string = "".join((string[:pos], char, string[pos:]))  # insert char at pos

print string
```

#### Update

Taken from [my answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599508/python-confused-about-random-choice-within-join/7599627#7599627) which is essentially derived from [DrTysra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595106/python-inserting-characters-between-other-characters-at-random-points/7595184#7595184):

```
from random import choice
S = 'Hello world. Hello world.'
L = ['!','-','=','~','|']
print ''.join('%s%s' % (x, choice((choice(L), ""))) for x in S)
```

Comment: In example chars can repeat. In your solution they don't. In example it can't be two chars in row.  In your solution it can. And doing `join` on every iteration isn't very effective.

Comment: Ah. Well spotted. So what's the criteria for deciding how many chars to insert, I wonder? Re performance: I'm aware of that. This smells like homework, hence the emphasis on clarity over performance. I've learnt the hard way that it's easier to optimise clear code than clean up optimised code.

Comment: Nope, it's not homework. I am actually working on something that will embed overlapping Unicode characters in between other characters for a POC on using these characters toward spoofing mechanisms. Blocks U+1DC0 – U+1DFF, U+FE20 – U+FE2F, and U+0300 – U+036F for reference.

Comment: @ShawnChin No worries at all.

Answer (score 0):

#### Python 3 Solutions

Inspired by DrTyrsa

```
import random

lst = ['!','-','=','~','|']
string = 'Hello world. Hello world.'
```

Using f-strings:

```
print(''.join(f"{x}{random.choice(lst) if random.randint(0,1) else ''}" for x in string))
```

Using `str.format()`

```
print(''.join("{}{}".format(x, random.choice(lst) if random.randint(0,1) else '') for x in string))
```

I replace `random() > 0.5` with `randint(0,1)` because I find it a bit more verbose while being shorter at the same time.