# Python: Confused about random.choice within join

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
s = 'Hello world'
c = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
n = ['1','2','3','4','5','6']
l = [random.choice(c),random.choice(n)]
return ''.join('%s%s' % (x, random.choice(l) if random.random() > 0.5 else '') for x in s)
```

This will output:

```
He5lloe w5o5rl5de
```

But what I am aiming for is something like this code would produce:

```
s = 'Hello world'
n = ['1','2','3','4','5','6']
return ''.join('%s%s' % (x, random.choice(n) if random.random() > 0.5 else '') for x in s)
```

Which is:

```
H4e3l3l6o wo4r3ld
```

It would be great if someone could also explain as to why the two are reacting differently than I would have assumed.

Sorry, I should have stated my intentions. I would like to randomly select an element from the two lists through each iteration of the for loop within join. Instead what I have is 2 elements being selected once and randomly choosing between the two elements selected.

This is what I don't want:

```
n = [1,2,3,4,5]
s = ['!','-','=','~','|']
l = [random.choice(n), random.choice(s)] # 1,!
# He1l!lo W!or1l!d
```

This is what I want:

```
n = [1,2,3,4,5] # 1 or 2 or 3... etc.
s = ['!','-','=','~','|'] # ! or - or =... etc.
> code to randomly select a list and a new element from that list
# He4ll-o W!or3l~d
```

Not sure if I have worded myself correctly, but hopefully it is understandable,

Comment: Please state your assumptions.  The code is very different, what did you assume about the first snippet?  Did you assume, for example, that the value of `l` would not simply be two characters?  Can you detail what you assumed, please?

Comment: @S.Lott I have made an update to my post. I should have stated my goal beforehand, my bad.

Comment: Related post (not dup): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595106/python-inserting-characters-between-other-characters-at-random-points

Comment: "Not sure if I have worded myself correctly".  Only you know what you want to accomplish and what you are assuming.  Take your time.  Write down numbered lists or pseudo-code or **anything** that helps you be sure you're really stating what you mean.  We can't guess.  (Also, don't bother with "status" comments.  We see the changes.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will get better at this. It'll just take some time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By doing `l = [random.choice(c),random.choice(n)]` you're limiting `random.choice(l)` to only 2 possible chars (one from each list `c` and `n`).

Try this instead:

```
from random import random, choice
s = 'Hello world'
c = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
n = ['1','2','3','4','5','6']
L = choice([c, n])  # randomly choose either c or n
return ''.join('%s%s' % (x, choice(L) if random() > 0.5 else '') for x in s)
```

As an aside, assuming you want to keep the probability of an insertion at `0.5`, that can also be written as:

```
# for each char, either append an empty string or a random char from list
return ''.join('%s%s' % (x, choice((choice(L), ""))) for x in s)
```

#### Update

Note that the above answer chooses a substitution list (`c` or `n`) and uses it for the whole process. If you want to be able to use both lists in the substitution, you can either create an intermediate list (`L = c + n`), or perform the list selection in-line.

```
# This is rather convoluted
return ''.join('%s%s' % (x, choice((choice(choice([c, n])), ""))) for x in s)
```

Alternatively,

```
e = ("", )  # tuple with a single empty element
return ''.join('%s%s' % (x, choice(choice([c, n, e, e]))) for x in s)
```

- Choose between `c`, `n`, or empty list `e` (`e` appears twice to keep the non-empty probability at 50%. Change as required)
- From the chosen list/tuple, choose a random element

Comment: I have made an update to my post for what I am trying to aim for. Though thank you for the latter, it looks a lot more readable than what I had.

Comment: @mikeyy I've update the question to match exactly what you've asked for in your edit (randomly select a list and a new element from that list).